# How can I convert my heap sort program to use C++ standard containers (for example std::vector)?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, stl, heapsort

I know how to code with C, however, this is my first time I try to use C++. And the use of VLAs(Variable Length Arrays) is not allowed in C++. So how can I convert this program to use C++ standard containers( for example std::vector) for the same instead of going the C route?

Instead of `int arr[n];` in `main()`, use `std::vector<int> arr(n);` and what further changes I have to do? Please assist.

Here is my code,

```
#include<iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
// A function to heapify the array.
void MaxHeapify(int a[], int i, int n)
{
    int j, temp;
    temp = a[i];
    j = 2*i;
 
    while (j <= n)
    {
        if (j < n && a[j+1] > a[j])
        j = j+1;
        // Break if parent value is already greater than child value.
        if (temp > a[j])
            break;
        // Switching value with the parent node if temp < a[j].
        else if (temp <= a[j])
        {
            a[j/2] = a[j];
            j = 2*j;
        }
    }
    a[j/2] = temp;
    return;
}
void HeapSort(int a[], int n)
{
    int i, temp;
    for (i = n; i >= 2; i--)
    {
        // Storing maximum value at the end.
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[1];
        a[1] = temp;
        // Building max heap of remaining element.
        MaxHeapify(a, 1, i - 1);
    }
}
void Build_MaxHeap(int a[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = n/2; i >= 1; i--)
        MaxHeapify(a, i, n);
}
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    cout<<"\nEnter the number of data element to be sorted: ";
    cin>>n;
    n++;
    int arr[n];
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter element "<<i<<": ";
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    // Building max heap.
    Build_MaxHeap(arr, n-1);
    HeapSort(arr, n-1);
 
    // Printing the sorted data.
    cout<<"\nSorted Data ";
 
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        cout<<"->"<<arr[i];
    cout<<"\nTime Complexity: Best case = Avg case = Worst case = O(n logn)";
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, `cin>>n;  n++; int arr[n];` does not look like valid C++ nor C.  C++ supports [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)?

Comment: Your C++ textbook should have an entire chapter that explains how to use vectors, and additional chapters on other containers and algorithms. Is there something specific in your textbook that's unclear to you? "How do I convert from language X to language Y" is off-topic for Stackoverflow, but we can answer ***specific*** questions.

Comment: C++ can still allocate arrays on the heap with dynamic size. `int* arr = new int[n];`.

Comment: The whole heap building can be a single call to: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And the use of VLAs(Variable Length Arrays) is not allowed in C++

I've just compiled your code in C++ and it works perfectly fine. Feel free to rephrase if you think I misunderstood you.
If you want to stick to arrays instead of `std::vector` you can use `std::array`. Otherwise in your case it would be mostly swapping `int[]` for `vector<int>` with `&` in function parameters.

Comment: VLAs are not a thing in c++. gcc an possibly other compilers allow them as a compiler-extension.

Comment: Try recompiling with `-predantic-errors`.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I did. It indeed outputs an error about variable size arrays. 
P.S. `-pedantic-errors` not `predantic`.